# Pasting an image on Word app failed, copying its link instead

Tags: images, motorola-moto-e, copy-paste, ms-office

I am unable to copy an image from internet and paste it on Word documents. When I copy the image, the image's link is copied to clipboard and when I paste it on Word document the link is pasted.

Can anyone tell me why am I unable to copy image to clipboard and how can I do so?

I'm using Motorola Moto E on Android KitKat 4.4.4 if it matters.

[image: Copying Image]
[image: Pasting Image]

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it depends on where you copy from. Also there might be some restriction on the file types you can copy (though images should be allowed).

Comment: @GiantTree I tried copying image from a webpage. I have tried copying with gif and jpg file types.

Comment: Does it say "Copy image" or "Copy image url"? There's a difference between these two ^^

Comment: @GiantTree It says Copy Image.

Comment: @GiantTree Added Images to the question.

Comment: I just tested it on my phone. It seems like word does not allow pasting anything but text. Maybe try another office app or paste it on PC.

Comment: @GiantTree Tried QuickOffice but didn't work. Any other office app suggestion.